# For which $n$ does $2^n+1$ divide $10^n+1$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

This came up in a discussion of numbers that divide their own binary representation (when interpreted as a decimal). The question I'm asking zooms in on a special case:

> For which $n$ does $2^n+1$ divide $10^n+1$?

I computed the remainder after division of $10^n+1$ by $2^n+1$ for $1 \leq n \leq 300$, which led me to suppose that there are no such $n$.

Comment: For odd $n$ we can observe that $3 | 2^n + 1$, but - using the ["lifting the exponent" lemma](http://www.taharut.org/imo/I5775/LTE.pdf) - we have $3 \not | 10^n + 1$, since $3 \not | 10 + 1$. **EDIT:** Or we can just use basic modular arithmetic....

Comment: I believe I've found a pattern that might be useful in this proof. We have $3|2^n + 1$, but then also $5|2^{4n + 2} + 1$, and $17|2^{8n + 4} + 1$ (because $2^4 \equiv 1 \mod(5)$ and $2^8 \equiv 1 \mod(17))$. In each instance, we can correspondingly see that $3 \not |10^n + 1$, that $5 \not |10^{4n+2} + 1$, and that $17 \not | 10^{8n + 4} + 1$. The pattern between $3, 5, 17...$ is that they are $2^{2^k} + 1$ for $k = 0, 1, 2$. It seems we might be able to get a contradiction proof this way - if I have time, I'll work on it further.

Comment: 10^n+1=(8+2)^n+1=O(8)+2^n+1. 2^n+1 does not divide O(8) because it is odd and O(8) is even. Therefore it does not divide 10^n+1 .

Comment: $10^n+1=(10^n-2^n)+(2^n+1)=2^n(5^n-1)+2^n+1$. Therefore we need to find $n$ which satisfies $2^n+1 | 5^n-1$.

Comment: $n=0$ works ;)       .

Comment: @Chris: thanks! You should put your observation as an answer (if you like), since it is now part of the solution, completed by Merdanov.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In comments on the question, Chris has proven all the cases other than $ $$8|n$.

If $ $ $ $$n=8k$,

Assume $2^n+1$ divides $5^n-1$ (that is equivalent to the main question as you can see easily).

Take any prime $p$ that divides 
$2^{8k}+1$, then $p\neq 2,5$ obviously and

$$\Rightarrow p|2^{16k}-1 $$

Assume $2^m||16k$ for some $m\geq4$,

Because $p$ does not divide $2^{8k}-1$,

$$\Rightarrow 2^m|p-1$$

Because $2^{8k}+1$ divides $5^{8k}-1$,
 $p$ divides $5^{8k}-1$,

$\Rightarrow$ 5 is square in modulo $p$.

$\Rightarrow \left (\dfrac {p}{5} \right ) \left (\dfrac {5}{p} \right )=(-1)^{\frac {p-1}{2} \frac {5-1}{2} }=1$

$\Rightarrow \left (\dfrac {p}{5} \right )=1 \Rightarrow$ $ p$ is square in modulo 5.

$\Rightarrow p\equiv 1,-1 \pmod {5}$

$\Rightarrow $ all prime divisors of $2^n+1$ are of the form $5k+1$ or $5k-1$.

$\Rightarrow 2^n+1 $ should be $\equiv 1,-1 \pmod {5}$,but $ 2^n+1=2^{8k}+1\equiv 2 \pmod {5} \Rightarrow \Leftarrow $.

Comment: That's absolutely terrific. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how Chris has proven all other cases. I only see that he found a _possible_ pattern which implies a factor of $2^n+1$ must be of the form $2^{2^k}+1$ (which he has not proved as of yet). Can you please add the other cases you're referencing (including proof) to your answer so it is complete?

Comment: What Chris is saying, I think, is that if $2^k$ is the highest power of $2$ dividing $n$, then $2^{2^k}+1$ divides $2^n+1$. (In fact, this is the observation that motivates the definition of the Fermat numbers $2^{2^k}+1$, since it proves no other numbers of the form $2^n+1$ can be prime.) This can be proven in an elementary way, using the following well-known fact: if $m$ is odd, then $a+1$ divides $a^m+1$ (even as polynomials). So writing $n = 2^k m$ with $m$ odd, it follows that $2^{2^k}+1$ divides $2^n+1$.

Comment: Applying this for $k=0$, it follows that if $n$ is odd, then $2^{2^0}+1=3$ divides $2^n+1$, whereas it's easy to see it doesn't divide $10^n+1$. For $k=1$, it follows that if $n$ is twice an odd number, then $2^{2^1}+1=5$ divides $2^n+1$, whereas it's even easier to see that it doesn't divide $10^n+1$. I haven't thought about the general divisibility of $10^n+1$ by numbers of the form $2^{2^k}+1$, but I'm sure you can do more with this line of argument if you want.

Comment: I can prove the following to myself.. If n is odd, then $3\mid 2^n +1$ but $3\nmid 5^n -1$. Therefore $n=2 n_1$ for some $n_1$. If $n_1$ is odd, then $5\mid 2^{2 n_1} +1$ but $5\nmid 5^{2 n_1}-1$. Therefore $n=4 n_2$ for some $n_2$. If $n_2$ is odd, then $17\mid 2^{4 n_2} +1$. However, I fail to prove to myself that $17\nmid 5^{4 n_2} -1$. Chris stated it without proof, and I don't see how to prove it. This is the only missing piece of the argument, because it would prove that $n = 8 n_3$ for some $n_3$, and @Merdanov's argument takes over.

Comment: We have $5^{4n_2} \equiv (5^4)^{n_2} \equiv (-4)^{n_2} \pmod{17}$ which since $n_2$ is odd equals $-4^{n_2}$. Now observe that $4^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{17}$, so the only possible values for $-4^{n_2}$ with $n_2$ odd are $4$ and $-4$.

Comment: @Andy My argument doesn't need the condition of $n=8k$, it needs $n=4t$ because $2^{4t}+1 \equiv 2 \pmod {5}$. Say $2^m||2n=8t$, then similarly it's done

Answer (score 3):

Pleased as I am with Merdanov's great answer, I would like to reformulate it, including the bit supplied by Chris, so as to make it a bit more concise and compatible with my way of looking at these things.

First the part done by Chris (actually, he went further, but I am only using what I need):

> Assume $2^n+1$ divides $10^n+1$. We prove that $n$ must be a multiple of $4$. Indeed, this was shown by Chris in the comments, since if $n$ were odd, we get $2^n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ whereas $10^n+1 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, and if $n$ were $2\pmod{4}$ we would have $2^n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ whereas $10^n+1 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$.

As Chris suggested, we could probably go on with this line of reasoning; see the comments on Merdanov's answer for more on this.

So now to Merdanov's answer. I use some (very) basic group theory in my reformulation, which is already implicit in what Merdanov wrote.

> First observe that $2^n+1$ must also divide $-(10^n+1)+5^n (2^n+1)$, which equals $5^n-1$. Let $p$ be a prime dividing $2^n+1$, then of course $p \mid 5^n-1$ as well, and $p \neq 2,5$. Since $p$ divides $2^n+1$ but not $2^n-1$, we have that $2n$ is a multiple of the order of $2$ in the cyclic group $C:=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$, whereas $n$ is not. Let $2^m$ be the highest power of $2$ dividing $2n$. Then $2^m$ divides the order of $2$ in $C$, hence also divides the order of $C$.
>
> Since $p \mid 5^n-1$, we have that $n$ is a multiple of the order of $5$ in $C$. Hence $2^{m-1}$ is the highest power of $2$ dividing the order of $5$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$, which means $5$ is a square in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$. By quadratic reciprocity, $p$ is a square modulo $5$, hence $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{5}$. Since $p$ was arbitrary, $2^n+1$ is a product of primes of the form $\pm 1 \pmod{5}$. Since we had already shown that $4 \mid n$, we get $2^n+1\equiv 1+1 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$, which is a contradiction.

This does suggest that "the numbers worked in our favour". If $10$ hadn't been a multiple of $2$ (if this slight abuse of language is permitted), then we couldn't have played the orders of the two elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ off against each other the way we did. Problems of the type where $a^n-1$ is supposed to divide $b^n+1$ would seem to be even more difficult to accomodate. But that would be a topic for some other time...